# I can't create an empty activity in java

Tags: android

Today I reinstalled android studio on my pc and the creation of empety activity does not exist the only one that exists is the one in the image and it does not let me change the project language from kotlin to java.

Does anyone know how to help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD8ZM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O11L2.png)

Answer (score 9):

You have to choose the `Empty Views Activity` from your screenshot. It will create the empty `Activity` and you will be able to choose the language as well.

[image]

Comment: "Empty views activity" its the same as "Empty Activity"?

Comment: Empty Activity will create Activity with the Jetpack Compose Support. It is written on Kotlin by default, so you can't choose a language. But Empty Views Activity is the Activity which uses XML files for layout (and can be written on Java or Kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you try to build a new app using Material 3 and

[Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), which only [supports Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/kotlin):

> Jetpack Compose is built around Kotlin.

If you want to create your app using Java, you have to choose one of the green Material 2 Activities, as e.g. "Empty Views Activity", where you can choose Java as language.

Answer (score 0):

Don't choose the Empty Activity option. Instead of that go with the No Activity option. With that, If you click on the Next button then on the next page you can select Java as your preferred language.[image]

If you select the Empty Activity option, it will create the default Activity with the support of Jetpack Compose, which only supports Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

From the photo, what you've selected is the Empty Compose Activity, to create the Empty Activity you are used to, go lower and click the Empty Views Activity.

Answer (score 0):

[Empty Views Actitvity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34ME0.png) `Empty Views Activity` Give you the Java as well as Kotlin Customisation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).